# Meaning of "のであり" in the sentence

Tags: translation, explanatory-の

Having translated a book dedicated to economy, I found out a bit unclear sentence for me. Could you please explain that?

> その手間が面倒な人がペットボトルのお茶を買う**のであり**、そう考えると、私たちはお茶そのものを買っているというよりは、「お茶を飲むために必要ないろいろな手間を節約してくれるサービス」を買っている**のです**。

Sorry for its length, but I really can't get the main point.

Like, we buy tea in the plastic bottle with thought that we pay for service and don't make any efforts instead of people who spend time and effort on that?

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot to unpack here. The attempted translation you proffered doesn't come all that close, so I've broken it down as shown below:

---

その手間が面倒な人
People (who find) that 'labor/time & effort' bothersome

が [subject marker]

ペットボトルのお茶を買う
buy PET bottles of tea

のであり、
explanatory/emphasizing の + continuous form of である（です）

そう考えると、
Thinking this way,

私たちはお茶そのものを買っているというよりは、
rather than us actually buying 'tea'

「お茶を飲むために必要ないろいろな手間
the various necessities of labor/time & effort in drinking tea

を節約してくれるサービス」を買っている
we are buying a service that is saving us

のです。
explanatory/emphasizing の + です

> People who find the effort of brewing their own tea bothersome buy PET bottles of tea, and thinking this way, rather than actually buying 'tea' we are buying a service that is saving ourselves from that necessary effort (that we find bothersome).

Your lack of inclusion as to what this 手間 is is supposedly 'brewing one's own tea'. If not, just substitute whatever that 手間 is.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native speaker of Japanese but not of English. So my English may not be natural but I hope to be helpful.

First, I think "のであり" in this sentence is a more assertive and more formal or politer expression of "ので". So "その手間が面倒な人がペットボトルのお茶を買うのであり" is almost the same as "その手間が面倒な人がペットボトルのお茶を買うので".
(But I am sorry I couldn’t find this usage in any dictionary I have.)
↑ I am really sorry. This explanation is incorrect.(edited 3/22)

Second “のです”’s definition in your sentence is:

> [のです](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172106/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/)
>   ［連語］《準体助詞「の」＋断定の助動詞「です」》「のだ」の意の丁寧な表現。(It is a politer equivalent of "のだ".)
>   １ 理由や根拠を強調した断定の意を表す。 (It is used to emphasize reasons or grounds.
>   e.g. 「注意をしないからけがをする―◦です」 (You get injured. This is because you aren’t careful.)

(I quoted these definitions from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/).)

Comment: この「のであり」は「の+である」であり、理由の「ので」とはひとまず別物だと思います。「5時がきたので帰ります」を「5時が来たのであり帰ります」とは言いませんよね。

Comment: 確かにその通りですね！私も初めは「の+である」だと考えていましたが、利用している辞書にしっくりくる定義がなかったことと、あの文脈では「ので」と言い換えてもほとんど同じ意味になるという理由からあのような回答を書きました。しかし、間違っていましたね。ご指摘ありがとうございます！訂正しておきます。

Comment: やっとわかりました。質問文の文章を少し言い換えると、「その手間が面倒な人がペットボトルのお茶を買うのである。そう(=前文)考えると…」ということですね。つまり、以下の定義の断定と説明にあたるわけですね。https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172103/meaning/m0u/のである/［連語］《断定の助動詞「なり」の連用形「に」に接続助詞「て」、補助動詞「あり」の付いた「にてあり」の音変化》

２ （「のである」「なのである」の形で）説明する意、または強く決意を表明する意を表す。「人間とは孤独なものなの―・る」

Comment: はい、「である」は「だ」の堅苦しい版であり、「であり」はその連用形ですね。「吾輩は猫で、彼奴は犬だ」「吾輩は猫であり、彼奴は犬である」のように対応しています。この「の (ん)」はかなり特殊な名詞の一種で、英語には直接対応する表現がないためこのサイトでも何度となく質問されています。[この記事](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/explanatory-noda/) が初心者向けですが、`日本語 ノダ` で検索すれば学術記事がいっぱい出てきます。

Comment: 大変勉強になりました！ありがとうございます！